# android gridLayoutManager - how to make equal spacing when recyclerview is constrained tot left and right side of screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a gridLayout which looks like this:

[image]

Notice how the layoutmanager forces the  column spacing between the items already. this is key. i have not yet added any item decorator for any spacing. this seems to be because i have constraint the recyclerview to both ends of the screen so its filling the items as much as it can.  i want to add row spacing equal to  this value so the grid looks evenly separated.  but how can i know the column spacing ahead of time ? or even after the view is laid out i could add a decoration possibly.

here is my recyclerview:

```
  <RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/rv"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:splitMotionEvents="false"
tools:background="@color/green"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:spanCount="3"
tools:listitem="@layout/grid_item"
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager" />
```

please note that if i do not not constraint the recyclerview to left and right then i can use the decorations fine using wrap_content. how can i resolve this issue of unequal spacing ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i figured this out and will give you some clues. gridlayoutmanager is scaling the items such that it will fit all items according to your span count. so imagine  when gridlayoutmanager takes your item, it will  says **how can i stretch this item such that X number of them can fit on a row ?**

the best approach i found is to use constraintLayout. such as:

```
 app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
```

and/or depending your usecase for your content you can use this so it stretches with the container:

eg.

```
app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".51"
app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".63"
```

for me the percentage stuff i used for the imageView so it keeps the ratio when stretched.

and not give any hard dimensions. Hard dimensions are going to make the spacing not even as its forcing a certain size when gridlayoutmanager wants to strength to fit your item. instead let the system scale the items but maintain the aspect ratio.

all these examples are for your container. inside your container you can create content as you usually do but you might still need ayout_constraintWidth_percent so it stretches when the item stretches proportionally.

after you do all that your items will be tightly bunched together with no spaces. now use a itemdecorator to add the spacing and it should work.